# How to flash U-Boot to a Devkit8500?

Tags: embedded, make, u-boot

When I try running this:

```
make CROSS_COMPILE=/root/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi- omap3devkit8000_config
```

I get this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `omap3devkit8000_config'.  Stop.
make: *** [omap3devkit8000_config] Error 1
```

How do I flash U-Boot to a Devkit8500? I'm using CentOS 6.3.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
make omap3_devkit8000_config CROSS_COMPILE=<your cross-compiler>
```

instead. You could run

```
find . -name omap3*
```

to determine, what board configurations do you have.

Answer (score -1):

Insert your SD card containing u-boot, u-bootfornadflasf, u-boot.bin, etc. with all the images. After doing this start the Linux kernel on the Devkit8500. Interrupt the u-boot and run the command:

```
Updatesys
```

Make sure that you have the correct images on your SD card because this operation is irreversible.

Comment: I am not sure I would want to do something irreversible based on such a vague description. Can you update the answer to a more elaborate description of the exact steps?

Comment: OP has a problem with make you seem to be answering a different question ?